# Can you refresh an SSIS Data Cube, from a SSMS database job?

Tags: sql, ssis, ssas, ssms

I have data cubes on a server, generated by SSIS. I would like to refresh the data cubes, without the need to create SSIS Packages, but with a database job or normal SQL.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

sure, just create a job step and on "type" select "SQL Server Analysis Services Command" and type your refresh command

FYI, this is an example:

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Parallel>
    <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2">
      <Object>
        <DatabaseID>DATABASE_NAME</DatabaseID>
        <CubeID>CUBE</CubeID>
      </Object>
      <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
      <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
    </Process>
  </Parallel>
</Batch>
```

or an even simpler way, if you need only one refresh each 24 hours, you could configure the proactive caching as "Scheduled Molap"